# Plone 4.1.3 migration fails

Tags: upgrade, plone

Ive upgraded using buildout from 4.0.5 to 4.1.3, but when I try to upgrade (first time login) I get this:

```
... ERROR plone.app.upgrade Upgrade aborted. Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.1.3-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/MigrationTool.py", line 175, in upgrade
    step['step'].doStep(setup)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/upgrade.py", line 140, in doStep
    self.handler(tool)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.1.4-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v41/alphas.py", line 105, in add_siteadmin_role
    for permission_id, roles in state.permission_roles.items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

...ERROR plone.app.upgrade Migration has failed
```

Upgrading steps:

```
Current
    4018
Latest
    4112
(4018 → 4019)
* No upgrade steps
(4019 → 4020)
* No upgrade steps
(4020 → 4022)
* No upgrade steps
(4022 → 4100)
* Add Site Administrator role
* Update role mappings
* Update control panel permissions
* Install plone.outputfilters
* Miscellaneous
(4100 → 4101)
* Miscellaneous
(4101 → 4102)
* Miscellaneous
(4102 → 4103)
* Miscellaneous
(4103 → 4104)
* Miscellaneous
(4104 → 4105)
* Miscellaneous
(4105 → 4106)
* Miscellaneous
(4106 → 4107)
* Miscellaneous
(4107 → 4108)
* Miscellaneous
(4108 → 4109)
* Miscellaneous
(4109 → 4110)
* Fix OkapiIndex total document lengths
(4110 → 4111)
* Repair owner tuples
* Miscellaneous
(4111 → 4112)
* Miscellaneous
```

Vangheem:
I tried the second solution by adding

```
         if state.permission_roles is None:
             continue
```

to

../buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.1.4-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v41/alphas.py

I do not know if its a problem but there are several alphas.py:

[root@www /usr/local/Plone]# find . -type f -name 'alphas.py'
./buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.0.5-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v30/alphas.py
./buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.0.5-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v40/alphas.py
./buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.1.4-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v30/alphas.py
./buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.1.4-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v40/alphas.py
./buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.1.4-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v41/alphas.py

Anyway, I then did the migration and it got a lot better -  I got this new error below though:

Role / permission map imported.
Step collective.blogging.reset-layers has an invalid import handler
Class Products.PloneboardSubscription.NotificationTool.NotificationTool not found for tool portal_pbnotification
Upgrade aborted. Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.1.3-py2.6.egg/Products/CMFPlone/MigrationTool.py", line 175, in upgrade
    step['step'].doStep(setup)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/upgrade.py", line 140, in doStep
    self.handler(tool)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.1.4-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v41/betas.py", line 112, in to41beta2
    loadMigrationProfile(context, 'profile-plone.app.upgrade.v41:to41beta2')
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.1.4-py2.6.egg/plone/app/upgrade/utils.py", line 112, in loadMigrationProfile
    context.runAllImportStepsFromProfile(profile, purge_old=False)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 323, in runAllImportStepsFromProfile
    ignore_dependencies=ignore_dependencies)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 1084, in _runImportStepsFromContext
    message = self._doRunImportStep(step, context)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 998, in _doRunImportStep
    return handler(context)
  File "/usr/local/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/Products/GenericSetup/tool.py", line 123, in importToolset
    new_tool = tool_class(tool_id)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
End of upgrade path, migration has finished
The upgrade path did NOT reach current version
Migration has failed
END

NB before the upgrade I removed Products.PloneboardSubscription from add-on and made an uninstall. Also I removed collective.blogging long time ago. Somehow there are still some references to it when trying to migrate:

There are unresolved or circular dependencies. Graphviz diagram:: digraph dependencies {"typeinfo" -> "toolset"; "tinymce_settings" -> "componentregistry"; "kss_mimetype" -> "mimetypes-registry-various"; "collective.blogging.reset-roles";"atcttool" -> "catalog"; "atcttool" -> "componentregistry"; "actions" -> "componentregistry"; "skins" -> "componentregistry"; "languagetool" -> "toolset"; "factorytool" -> "componentregistry"; "factorytool" -> "typeinfo"; "ploneboard-various" -> "toolset"; "ploneboard-various" -> "typeinfo"; "ploneboard-various" -> "placeful_workflow"; "placeful_workflow" -> "typeinfo"; "placeful_workflow" -> "workflow"; "portal-transforms-various" -> "componentregistry"; "componentregistry" -> "toolset"; "plone.app.caching";"controlpanel" -> "actions"; "controlpanel" -> "componentregistry"; "placeful_marker" -> "workflow"; "jsregistry" -> "toolset"; "jsregistry" -> "componentregistry"; "action-icons" -> "componentregistry"; "plone.app.registry" -> "componentregistry"; "plone.app.registry" -> "toolset"; "mimetypes-registry-various" -> "componentregistry"; "reference_catalog" -> "toolset"; "viewlets" -> "componentregistry"; "content" -> "typeinfo"; "collective.blogging.reset-catalog";"propertiestool" -> "componentregistry"; "various" -> "toolset"; "collective.blogging.reset-views";"portlets" -> "componentregistry"; "portlets" -> "content"; "content_type_registry" -> "componentregistry"; "plone-final" -> "kss_mimetype"; "plone-final" -> "portlets"; "plone-final" -> "rolemap"; "kssregistry" -> "toolset"; "kssregistry" -> "componentregistry"; "poi_various" -> "catalog"; "ploneopenid-various";"update-workflow-rolemap" -> "workflow"; "sharing" -> "rolemap"; "uid_catalog" -> "toolset"; "workflow" -> "toolset"; "collective.plonetruegallery.install";"cssregistry" -> "toolset"; "cssregistry" -> "componentregistry"; "contentrules" -> "componentregistry"; "contentrules" -> "content"; "catalog" -> "toolset"; "simpleattachment" -> "properties"; "simpleattachment" -> "typeinfo"; "cookie_authentication" -> "toolset"; "cmfeditions_various" -> "toolset"; "cmfeditions_various" -> "typeinfo"; "difftool" -> "toolset"; "difftool" -> "componentregistry"; "plone-content" -> "plone-final"; "toolset";"properties";"collective.blogging.reset-layers";"plonepas" -> "componentregistry"; "plonepas" -> "controlpanel"; "plonepas" -> "memberdata-properties"; "plonepas" -> "plonepas-contents"; "plonepas" -> "rolemap"; "jquerytools-various" -> "cssregistry"; "tinymce_various" -> "componentregistry"; "browserlayer" -> "componentregistry"; "plone-difftool";"plone_outputfilters_various" -> "componentregistry"; "memberdata-properties" -> "componentregistry"; "Products.EasyNewsletter-setuphandlers";"plonetheme.sunburst-various" -> "actions"; "caching_policy_mgr" -> "toolset"; "archetypetool" -> "archetypes-various"; "mailhost" -> "componentregistry"; "repositorytool" -> "toolset"; "repositorytool" -> "typeinfo"; "repositorytool" -> "cmfeditions_various"; "Products.Ploneboard.uninstallVarious";"various-calendar" -> "toolset"; "collective.flowplayer" -> "kupu-setup"; "collective.flowplayer" -> "propertiestool"; "kupu-setup" -> "toolset"; "kupu-setup" -> "typeinfo"; "archetypes-various" -> "componentregistry"; "rolemap";"plonepas" [color=red,style=filled]; }

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed with this commit: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.upgrade/commit/df61c3b4eabaf2cacb1f57bf1cd06e035d19ece9

If you do a check out of this branch:

https://github.com/plone/plone.app.upgrade/tree/1.1

install it and then run the upgrade, you should be good.

Comment: Hi vangheem, please check out my editing above. Thanks. Nikolaj

Answer (score 1):

Others have reported similar errors before... see http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/migration-from-plone-4-0-10-to-plone-4-1-3-fails-td7055584.html for one solution.

Comment: Hi Jon. Ok, so if I go this direction I should to into /portal_workflow/manage_selectWorkflows and set all roles to "Authenticated" on items that are not "default". Correct? PS Ive tried the solution from vangheem also, please see my edit on the original post. Thanks. Nikolaj G.